# Does the Easter Bunny have any canonical status as existing/not existing within the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Within the canon of the MCU, including the movies, comic books, tie-in novels, and animated series, is there any canonical information regarding the existence or non-existence of the Easter Bunny as actual physical creatures that exist outside of the in-universe popular culture?

For example, has the Easter Bunny ever been shown to exist, in a similar way to Thor and Loki being real characters upon whom the Norse myths are based?

Conversely, has the Easter Bunny been referenced as being a purely fictional character within the fictional setting of the MCU?

Answers citable to media only please, not supposition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not a Marvel expert to know how this would be answered, but especially if they have been treated differently, or their status has changed over time, it might be better to ask a separate question about each.

Comment: @DavidW, I'm only asking about the MCU

Comment: Tony Stark as the Easter Bunny; https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuvie.jpg

Comment: I'd say the most important factor here is how soon Disney can acquire the Easter Bunny as part of its intellectual property.

Comment: [Cross-post on M&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118548).

Comment: [On Santa Claus in the MCU.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/119068/1006) (Movies & TV SE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Easter Bunny hasn't been mentioned in the MCU (nor any of its more obvious tie-in materials such as the prose novels, novelisations, graphic novels or games set in the MCU), hence its current canonical status is **'unknown'**

The closest we've got so far is a satirical Easter tweet from Marvel UK referencing Thor's apparent inability to tell the difference between a racoon and a rabbit.

[image]

---

Within the Marvel-616 (mainstream comic) continuity the Easter Bunny exists as a *fictional character*. It is repeatedly mentioned in a wide variety of comic lines including Squirrel Girl, Black Panther, Howard the Duck, Spider-Man, Amazing Spider-Man, etc. but does not appear to be a real individual, unlike other magical beings such as [Santa Claus](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Santa_Claus_(Earth-616)).

Comment: Tricks are for kids, yo. Oh, that was an allusion to the Easter Bunny....

Comment: @Mazura - An allusion to the Trix rabbit.